# How to send a complex request and save a complex response (service) in ROS?

Tags: yaml, bagfiles, service, rosparam, bagfile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I don´t have a high level in ROS so I would request your help.
Last weeks I was trying to make a client for testing that package https://github.com/sniekum/dmp
Alwais I had problems running it (the client) so I decided to run it by CMD

I used this commands to send the request to one of the service´s package:

```
rosservice call /learn_dmp_from_demo "{'demo': {'points': [{'positions': [1.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [4.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [6.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [4.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [6.55], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [6.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [5.05], 'velocities': [0]}, {'positions': [2.05], 'velocities': [0]}], 'times': [0, 0.15, 0.65, 1.3, 2.32, 3.5, 4.8, 5.9, 7]}, 'd_gains': [0.5], 'k_gains': [1.5], 'num_bases': 50}"
```

I got this response:

```
dmp_list: 
  - 
    k_gain: 1.5
    d_gain: 0.5
    weights: []
    f_domain: [0.0, 0.02542372881355932, 0.11016949152542373, 0.22033898305084745, 0.3932203389830508, 0.5932203389830508, 0.8135593220338982, 1.0]
    f_targets: [0.0, 3526.023021050232, -1212.684557129261, -707.1580492824511, 827.153942036789, -818.845524643713, -197.3391387004624, -4666.23882178427]
tau: 7.0
```

So It was succesfull.
The question is, How can I send the request without command line? and store the response in a YAML file for using it later?
I was reading about Ros Param Server and bag files and store YAML files, but I´m a little bit lost with it

Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262492/how-to-send-a-complex-request-and-save-a-complex-response-(service)-in-ros?/) by [mdcr](https://answers.ros.org/users/30505/mdcr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-05-27**:
Writing a node which has the service client for `learn_dmp_from_demo` is the right direction. Maybe you can share what problem you were having when writing this service client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @mdcr!

To call a service without command line, I recommend you to go tough the [Writing a Simple Service and Client (Python)](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29) tutorial.

If you prefer C++, there is a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29) for that also.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12470665/how-can-i-write-data-in-yaml-format-in-a-file) will help you save the data in YAML format using Python.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2017-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1